# что значит ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс находится вне границ массива

Tags: pascalabc.net

Задание звучало так: Найти наибольшее количество подряд идущих цифр. Я написал такую программу, но ничего не работает из-за этой ошибка и главное не понятно почему.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите код текстом, а не скриншотом

Comment: *"Индекс находится вне границ массива"* - вот все сказано же .. и строка указана в которой ошибка произошла - 16

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.